# How to get specific branch from chart repository for Helmfile

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helmfile

Do I need to include repositories field in Helmfile, If it is the local helm chart and It would not be needed to be donwloaded?

Right now I have folloving helmfile.yaml:

```
repositories:
- name: system-test
  url: https://github.com/test/test.system.configuration.git

releases:
- name: system-test-release
  chart: ./charts/test
  namespace: system-test
  values:
    - ./charts/test/values.yaml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `repositories:` would only get used if you're actually pulling a chart from that repository; for example

```yaml
releases:
  - name: end-to-end
    chart: system-test/end-to-end
```

If you're just referring to local charts with filesystem paths, the `repositories:` don't get used.